# Is `xcov()` More Accurate Than `xcorr()` to Compute the Cross Correlation of Signals with Non Zero Mean Values?

Tags: matlab, cross-correlation, distance-metrics

I have to compute the cross-correlation between two **transient signals**, which could be decomposed into a **trend (with non-zero mean value) + noise**.

In particular I am interested in the max of the cross-correlation.

It seems that in MATLAB the cross-correlation is more accurate if it is calculated  using the function `xcov()` rather then `xcorr()`, probably as a consequence of the fact that the function `xcov()` **removes the mean value of the signal**.

An example of two signals between which I would have to measure similarity can be this one:

[image]

Do you know if this makes sense and why?

Comment: covariance and correlation are simply two different things – if you want one, then you don't want the other and vice versa. What is it that you need this for? That defines which you want.

Comment: I'd like to compute the max of the cross-correlation as a measure of similarity between the two signals

Comment: then, the correlation is indeed what you want, otherwise high-variance signals have a high chance of showing an exceedingly large metric

Comment: I agree. But do I have to remove the mean value to optimize the MATLAB routine? If I don't do that, I have a case in which the max of the  cross-correlation of two slightly different signals (but not identical) computed with xcorr is higher then the max value of the auto-correlation (so in this case the two signals are identical), still computed using xcorr,. This doesn't make sense to me. If I remove the mean value, this doesn't happen. Does this depend on the MATLAB algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to measure similarity between signals we're basically building a metric.
When doing so we need to ask what we want to be sensitive about.

For instance, if you don't remove the DC Component (The Mean) and use something like an integral to measure similarity (Correlation / Convolution based) then you are sensitive the added DC component.

For instance, take 2 random white noises and add to each a DC component of `1e6`.
Measure their similarity by correlation and compare it to 2 Sine Waves with amplitude of `1e-3` and a relative shift phase of `1e-6 [Rad]`.
In your eyes, which should be more similar? Which is indeed?

I'd say that in most cases in signal processing, similarity should be measured ignoring the DC component.

Comment: In my case, I don't have an actual DC components, because my signals are transients, so they represent the quick evolution of a variable. Do you think that the mean value should also be removed in this case? In this case, it is even hard to define a mean value, actually there is a trend + superimposed noise.
In addition, I suspect that a mean value interferes with the MATLAB algorithm, which uses the FFT to compute the cross-correlation rapidly. Probably this algorithm is optimized for signals with a DC component (more or less constant in time) + zero-mean components/noise. What do you think?

Comment: I modified the question, to be more specific.

Comment: Is it like rise? Can you model it in a parametric model?

Comment: I think that the shape does not matter so much. As an example, you can imagine a ramp, a successive flat part with a pulse inside and then a descent ... with superimposed noise of course

Comment: Could you share a plot of such signals?

Comment: I added a figure. Please let me know if it is now clear to you what I mean.

Comment: Can you add `csv` file with 2 signals you would like to set the similarity between?

Comment: For the moment, I can't share this information, as those are data I am working with and so confidential. I think what I have shared is enough for a general consideration, isn't it?

Comment: The problem is I don't fully understand what you want to see is similar between 2 signals. If it is the part in the middle which slowly goes down I'd use a parametric model and between 2 signals I'd check the similarity between the parameters.

Comment: I don't have a parametric model, but if you know how to build one, please let me know or tell me how I can find information about it. Thanks.

Comment: In order to build parametric model we need to see a set of signals. Not only one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I modified the question by adding a figure also with a second signal. I cannot build a parametric model, because I just have two signals unfortunately, not a set of signals (not even a set of two signals). Any more suggestions?

Comment: I think this question is about `xcov()` and `xcorr()`. I answered it. Please mark it and open a question about specifically those 2 question and I will suggest a parametric model.

Comment: I am not sure about your answer, please make it clearer. After you do it, I will probably accept it. Thanks

Comment: Can you pin point me what's not clear and I will clarify?

Comment: This part is not so clear to me "For instance, take 2 random white noises and add to each ... Which is indeed?"
And also I think that the term DC component is not appropriate here, as we are not dealing with electric signals ... 
What do you think?

Comment: DC Component in DSP is basically the Mean of a signal. Regarding to the white noises I wanted to show the case the Mean of 2 signals hides the fast they are basically so different. Hence it makes sense in most cases not to measure it.

Comment: My question was about two signal with a trend, not with a constant mean value. Maybe you can make another example? It would be more appropriate. Thank you.

Comment: @EmThorns, It doesn't matter what was the signal. The average value of it might shadow other components when using "Euclidean Distance" as a measure of similarity. Hence, in most cases, using this as a similarity measure it makes sense to remove the DC component.

Comment: I understand your point, and I will probably accept your answer. However, I think you should include this consideration in the answer too.
 In addition, are you sure that the fact that MATLAB uses the FFT to compute the cross-correlation in xcorr does not have an effect on this, because the FFT is biased by the presence of a mean value at low frequencies?

Comment: By definition of the math operation covariance removes the means while correlation doesn't. Hence in MATLAB using `xcorr()` doesn't remove the mean regardless if it is computed in frequency domain or not (As the result is the same). I lost you on "this consideration". Which one? Your signals being a trend like? This is why I offered that you use a parametric model and measure the similarity by the values of the parameters.

Comment: I cannot define a parametric model, since my signals are measured recordings ... 
In my last comments I was comparing the using of the function xcorr (which exploits the FFT) and the straight use of the correlation sequence formula. If you can't comment on this, I will try to further explore this by making some trials.

Comment: Your signals being recorded has nothing to do with the ability to have a parametric model. From the image above, if most of them look somehow similar, it can be done. It doesn't matter how `xcorr()` is implemented. The result on time or frequency domain is the same.